# java jfreechart library bubble size issue

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an a jfreechart application that shows the values of three variables in a bubble chart. I have issues with make the bubbles on the graph show. It is only visible when you try to zoom out.
But if Ii change the values in the third column/array to whole numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, the bubbles start becoming visible. Please can anyone help me out. I want the bubbles to have a specific size for all the plotted points.

Below is my source code:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Shape;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYZDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYZDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import org.jfree.util.ShapeUtilities;

public class JavaApplication2 extends ApplicationFrame {

    public JavaApplication2(String s) {
        super(s);
        JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560, 370));
        setContentPane(jpanel);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYZDataset xyzdataset) {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createBubbleChart(
            "AGE vs WEIGHT vs WORK",
            "Weight",
            "AGE",
            xyzdataset,
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL,
            true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyplot.setForegroundAlpha(0.65F);
        XYItemRenderer xyitemrenderer = xyplot.getRenderer();
        xyitemrenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        NumberAxis numberaxis = (NumberAxis) xyplot.getDomainAxis();
        numberaxis.setLowerMargin(0.2);
        numberaxis.setUpperMargin(0.5);
        NumberAxis numberaxis1 = (NumberAxis) xyplot.getRangeAxis();
        numberaxis1.setLowerMargin(0.8);
        numberaxis1.setUpperMargin(0.9);

        return jfreechart;
    }

    public static XYZDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultXYZDataset defaultxyzdataset = new DefaultXYZDataset();

        double ad[] = {426081.759473, 426095.238564, 426109.490941, 426121.967623, 426130.564392, 426138.69481};
        double ad1[] = {113322.88289, 113271.915074, 113221.586484, 113172.511533, 113128.370338, 113085.254484};
        double ad2[] = {0.460819752574555, 0.850726080807893, 0.571903719860673, -0.013658463858901, -0.231945599223777, -0.256564887488579};
        double ad3[][] = {ad, ad1, ad2};
        defaultxyzdataset.addSeries("Series 1", ad3);

        return defaultxyzdataset;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
        ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart);

        chartpanel.setDomainZoomable(true);
        chartpanel.setRangeZoomable(true);

        return chartpanel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JavaApplication2 bubblechart = new JavaApplication2("Bubble Chart_frame");

        bubblechart.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(bubblechart);
        bubblechart.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post your code in external sources, instead create and post a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates your issue. Please take the [tour] and through the [help] while you learn [ask], otherwise your question might get closed because it's posting your code in external sources, what would happen if someday your code disappears from Google Drive? This question won't be helpful anymore for future readers

Comment: thanks but can you help out i new, so i don't understand how to do it

Comment: *"can you help out"* Help out with what? *"i don't understand how to do it"* How to do what thing? As per your fast reply I assume you haven't read even one of the links provided before. Please fix your question after you have read all of them if you don't understand something of the links you can ask, but please read them

Answer (score 2):

By default, [`ChartFactory.createBubbleChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.2355) specifies an [`XYBubbleRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBubbleRenderer.html) having `SCALE_ON_RANGE_AXIS`, but your *x* and *y* data are several orders of magnitude larger that your *z* data. As a result, no pixels are visible. You'll probably need to [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_chart) the data to get the desired effect. You can see the effect on your data by using a default renderer and zooming in on both axes using the context menu (right-click):

```
XYBubbleRenderer renderer = new XYBubbleRenderer(); //SCALE_ON_BOTH_AXES
xyPlot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

[image: zoomed bubble chart]

In the reference example below, I've used simpler data in a `VERTICAL` plot to make experimentation easier. Note that the sizes of the bubbles at (1, 1), (2, 2) and (3, 3) are in the ratio of the *z* coordinates: <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub>:<sup>3</sup>/<sub>3</sub>:<sup>4</sup>/<sub>3</sub>

[image: XYZ bubble chart]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBubbleRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYZDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYZDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
import static org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBubbleRenderer.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41575283/230513 */
public class BubbleChartTest extends ApplicationFrame {

    public BubbleChartTest(String s) {
        super(s);
        JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560, 370));
        setContentPane(jpanel);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYZDataset xyzDataset) {
        JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createBubbleChart(
            "X vs Y vs Z", "X", "Y", xyzDataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
        xyPlot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5F);
        XYBubbleRenderer renderer = new XYBubbleRenderer(SCALE_ON_BOTH_AXES);
        xyPlot.setRenderer(renderer);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setLowerMargin(0.2);
        domain.setUpperMargin(0.4);
        NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setLowerMargin(0.2);
        range.setUpperMargin(0.4);

        return jfreechart;
    }

    public static XYZDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultXYZDataset dataset = new DefaultXYZDataset();
        double a[][] = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {1, 2, 3},
            {2 / 3d, 3 / 3d, 4 / 3d}
        };
        dataset.addSeries("Series", a);
        return dataset;
    }

    public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setDomainZoomable(true);
        chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(true);
        return chartPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BubbleChartTest test = new BubbleChartTest("Bubble Chart");
        test.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(test);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked it the pixels only seems to appear when you zoom in, but is there any other way i can make the pixel appear automatically without zooming in. Like make all the sizes of the pixels appear the same, that the same size, so that the person can see the points without zooming in.

Comment: Scaling is the only way I know; you can display the unscaled data in a tool tip.

Comment: Please i have a range of data coming from the database and i want the graph to display the data such that values in the third column, depending on the range will be have a particular color. for example 0- 3 will be red and -0 to -3 will be green and so on, so please how can you be of assistance to me. thanks i appreciate your help

Comment: Include representative data and your chosen scaling approach in your [mcve].